# Adding , removing items to and from a ListBox after binding

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, listbox

In following button event I'm adding items to a list from another list.

```
    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lstPermissions.SelectedItem != null)
        if (!lstGivenPermissions.Items.Contains(lstPermissions.SelectedItem))
        {
            lstGivenPermissions.Items.Add(lstPermissions.SelectedItem);
        }
    }
```

When the Items were hard coded in `lstPermissions` and `lstGivenPermissions`'s `datasource` is not set , it was fine. But After binding data to `lstGivenPermissions`, when I try to execute this method I'm getting this exception.

***Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.***

I'm using this property to bind data to the `lstGivenPermissions`

```
    public List<string>  GivenPermission
    {
        get { return lstGivenPermissions.Items.Cast<string>().ToList(); }
        set { lstGivenPermissions.DataSource = value; }
    }
```

I can understand that the databinding has caused this exception. But my requirement is that I want to load all permissions to `lstPermissions` and selected user's permissions to `lstGivenPermission` from the database. Then I should be able to add and remove items to and from `lstGivenPermissions`. Could you let me know how to do this?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to modify the ListBox.Items collection after settings the DataSource property. You can't, bind it to an ObservableCollection and add/remove items on said collection.

Comment: Not sure if `ObservableCollection` is the right way to go for `winforms`, but @RodrigoSilva is right, don't delete items, call method `Delete` of underlying data source provider (view model in wpf), which then update data and inform UI about changes somehow (never used binding in `winforms`, sorry).

Comment: If your control is data bound you must change its contents by changing the data of the underlying datasource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using a property to bind to a list control... Properties should just save/load values, like so:

```
private List<string> _givenPermission;
public List<string>  GivenPermission
{
    get { return _givenPermission; }
    set { _givenPermission = value;}
}
```

If you must bind, try doing it this way instead:

```
private List<string> _givenPermission;
public List<string>  GivenPermission
{
    get { return _givenPermission; }
    set { _givenPermission = value; lstGivenPermissions.DataSource = value; }
}
```